# When Upgrade to DSpace 7.6, the tomcat give 404 Error

Tags: tomcat, repository, dspace, custom-error-pages

I have installed DSpace 7.5, now I want to upgrade it to DSpace 7.6. So I have followed the instructions in the documentation as below:

1. checked the versions of java and ant and maven ..etc , all were the right version.
2. download DSpace 7.6 zip file and unzip it.
   unzip dspace-7.6.zip
3. mvn -U clean package - BUILD SUCCESS
4. systemctl stop tomcat9.service
5. cp local.cfg.EXAMPLE local.cfg
6. configure the local.cfg file to see the path of dspace file, solr, postgresal database
7. dspace-installer# ant update - BUILD SUCCESSFUL
8. ./dspace database migrate
9. cp -R /dspace/webapps/* /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps*
10. cp /dspace/solr/search/conf/schema.xml /opt/solr-8.11.2/server/solr/configsets/search/conf/
11. ./solr restart -force
12. ./dspace index-discovery -b
13. systemctl restart tomcat9.service

Dspace 7.5 backend was working fine, but now whit upgrading to DSpace7.6 the tomcat URL: localhost:8080/server give the below message:

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
status report
the requested resource [/server] is not available.

I have tried many solutions in permissions and  other but nothing has worked.

Please, what can I do to know what is the problem?

I have tried many solutions in permissions and  other but nothing has worked.
I am expecting the server of DSpace to work.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem. I'm facing a similar issue with 7.6

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it.

You need to remove the server file inside the tomcat instead of overwrite on it.

Remove the schema.xml file in solar instead of overwrite on it.

Remove the files first and then copy them to the path.

good luck.